# Swift 4: Opacity constantly overlaps in one stroke (Drawing App)

Tags: swift, core-graphics

The opacity overlaps in one stroke rather than it being one solid opaque stroke.[Opacity Stroke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjoz5.png)

I have tried modifying some of the contexts and even deleted some, however non of that helped (I have turned it back to its original state). My goal is to try and draw with the marker tool and have the opacity be around .5 comparing to the pencil tool with opacity as 1. When I use the marker, all I get are constant dots as seen in the picture, I believe that they are all separate strokes even with one swipe without lifting up my finger.

If anyone has any knowledge on this I could really use some help (:

Here is my Core Graphics code.

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    swiped = true
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let currentPoint = touch.preciseLocation(in: self.view)
        drawLines(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint)
        lastPoint = currentPoint
        tool.center = currentPoint

    }
}
func drawLines(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
    imageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: fromPoint.x, y: fromPoint.y))
    context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: toPoint.x, y: toPoint.y))
    context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: opacityValue).cgColor)
    context?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
    context?.setLineJoin(CGLineJoin.bevel)
    context?.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
    context?.setLineWidth(brushSize)
    context?.strokePath()

    imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if !swiped {
        drawLines(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint)

    }
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    touchesEnded(touches, with: event)

}

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you draw each each line segment onto the image as individual line segments. And since each segment overlaps and you are using a partially transparent color, the overlapped transparent areas appear darker.

One solution would be to keep an array of all of the points that have been drawn (instead of just the latest and previous points). Then construct a single path consisting of all of the line segments between all of the points and then stroke that single path. This will eliminate the darker overlapped areas.